# How do you create a new database with new sid on Oracle's pre-built 11g virtual machine?

Tags: oracle-11g

I downloaded [DeveloperDaysVM2016-06-02_13.ova](http://download.oracle.com/otn/other/virtualbox/dd/DeveloperDaysVM2016-06-02_13.ova) from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/databaseappdev-vm-161299.html and successfully loaded it into Virtual Box.

I logged in as "oracle" user and I can see the desktop.

From within the virtual machine, I opened Firefox and navigated to:

http://localhost:8080/ords/hrrest/employees/ and successfully received a list of employees in JSON format. So I know the database is up and running.

I noticed the local pre-built database is on port 1521 using SID:XE by default.

Also, in order to access it from an external oracle Java driver I had to use the credentials "hr"/"oracle", which is the default credential for this virtual machine.

My question: Is there a wizard I can use to create a brand new database? Or, if there are commands that do this, what documentation shows how to do this?

I want a new database, with a new username and password, with a new ORACLE_SID.

How do I do this? Is there a link to oracle documentation that shows me how to do this? This virtual machine uses Oracle 11g.

Ideally, I would like to connect to this new database with a Java program using new credentials like:

username:newuser
password:newpass
localhost
1521
ORACLE_SID=newsid

Comment: You can not create a second instance (=database) with Oracle Express. Why do you think you need that? Just create  new user (=schema) and use that.

Comment: The wizard is called DBCA (database creation Assistent), however you might need to clean up some stuff and I am not sure if it is part of that actual VM.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that your Developer Days VM 2016-06-02_13 runs Oracle 11g?  I'm using the same, and it reports:

```
SQL> select * from v$version;

BANNER                                                                               CON_ID
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production              0
PL/SQL Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production                                                    0
CORE    12.1.0.2.0  Production                                                                  0
TNS for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production                                            0
NLSRTL Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production                                                    0
```

Reading your questions/explanations, I cannot tell how familiar you are with 12c's "multitenant option", which "allows a single container database (CDB) to host multiple separate pluggable databases (PDB)" (see eg [oracle-base.com](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/multitenant-create-and-configure-pluggable-database-12cr1)).  For starters, a new PDB may be just what you need ... an overview of Oracle Multitenant can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/ADMIN/overview-of-managing-a-multitenant-environment.htm#ADMIN13507).

In this [article](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2014/02/introducing-the-otn-developer-day-database-12c-virtualbox-image/), section "Where to get started", you can see that the *SERVICE NAME* (not the SID) is used for connecting to a PDB.  More about PDBs (cloning etc), with screen shots, can be found [here](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/12c/r1/12c_sqldev/pdb/12cPDB01.html).  SQLDeveloper (already installed on the Developer Days VM) is probably the best tool for getting started.  I'm not aware of any "wizards" that one could use.

Using Java: When connecting to a PBD, using a JDBC driver, make sure that you use the service name (again: not the SID).

SID (for connections): it seems that the SID is only used for connecting to CDBs (not PDBs) nowadays.  Although - I have also used the "service name" successfully for accessing CDBs.

Comment: I downloaded the developer days VM sometime last year, and so it came with Oracle 11, not 12. I'm trying to stick to using Oracle 11 because that's what the customer is using. I'll look into the PDF stuff, but I'm not sure it will work in Oracle 11.

Comment: Even the 2014 version of the Developer Days VM already had a Oracle 12c installation (see the third link in my answer).  However, if you need to stick to 11g,  all the "multitentant" documentation is probably no use to you.